# jQuery AJAX transformando em link

Tags: jquery, ajax

Como faço para deixar como link o resultado o meu banco em jQuery AJAX?

```
function carregaRoteiro(){
    var roteiroHTML="";
    $.ajax({
    url: path + "RoteiroAula",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
            roteiroHTML += '<div class="roteiroAula">'+
                             '<p id="roteiroId_'+data[i].idroteiro_aula+'"><span>Roteiro:</span>'+data[i].roteiro+'</p>'+
                           '</div>';
        };

        $('#box_roteiroAula').html(roteiroHTML);
    }
});
```

Comment: Depende, pra onde o link deve apontar?

Answer (score 0):

A questão não é o resultado do banco é como você quer este link e pra onde ele deve apontar, vamos supor que você queira usar o `idroteiro_aula` pra gerar o link, então já que está usando `.html` basta escrever o link assim (dentro de `<p>`), segue pedaço do código:

```
success: function (data) {

    for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        roteiroHTML += '<div class="roteiroAula">'+
                         '<p id="roteiroId_'+data[i].idroteiro_aula+'">'+
                         '<a href="pagina/?id=' + data[i].idroteiro_aula  + '">'+
                         '<span>Roteiro:</span>'+data[i].roteiro+
                         '</a>'+
                         '</p>'+
                       '</div>';
    };

    $('#box_roteiroAula').html(roteiroHTML);
}
```

Os links gerados ficarão semelhantes a isto:

```
<div class="roteiroAula">
    <p id="roteiroId_1">
       <a href="pagina/?id=1"><span>Roteiro:</span>Foo</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="roteiroAula">
    <p id="roteiroId_2">
       <a href="pagina/?id=2"><span>Roteiro:</span>Bar</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="roteiroAula">
    <p id="roteiroId_3">
       <a href="pagina/?id=3"><span>Roteiro:</span>Baz</a>
    </p>
</div>
```